# SharePoint | Delete Version History using PnP PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, version-control, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to execute the script below from [SharePoint Diary](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/05/sharepoint-online-delete-version-history-using-pnp-powershell.html).

And it works for me... partially. I do have version deletions, but as soon as the script scans a large file, I get errors in the terminal. The most common being :

```
        Scanning File: file.psd
Get-PnPProperty: C:\Users\Thibault\SharePoint_ClearLibraryVersionHistory.ps1:19
Line |
  19 |  …    $Versions = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $File -Property Versions
     |                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
```

Indeed, it has many psd and psb files in the document library, they are heavy (several GB) and these are precisely the ones we want to delete and that the script ignores.

I spend day and night reading all possible documentation but without success. I'm a bit desperate to say the least^^

Thank you very much in advance for your help ;)

```
#Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/IC"
$LibraryName = "Energy"
  
Try {
    #Connect to PnP Online
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive
 
    #Get the Library
    $Library = Get-PnPList -Identity $LibraryName
    $global:counter=0
 
    #Get All Items from the List - Get 'Files
    $ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $Library -Fields FileLeafRef,FileRef -PageSize 2000 -ScriptBlock { Param($items) $global:counter += $items.Count; Write-Progress `
                    -PercentComplete ($global:Counter / ($Library.ItemCount) * 100) -Activity "Getting Files of '$($Library.Title)'" `
                       -Status "Processing Files $global:Counter of $($Library.ItemCount)";} | Where {($_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "File")} 
    Write-Progress -Activity "Completed Retrieving Files!" -Completed
 
    #Loop through each file
    $global:counter=1
    ForEach ($Item in $ListItems)
    {
        #Get File and File Versions
        $Versions = Get-PnPFileVersion -Url $Item.FieldValues.FileRef
        Write-host -f Yellow "Scanning File ($global:counter of $($Library.ItemCount)) : $($Item.FieldValues.FileRef)"
       
        If($Versions.Count -gt 0)
        {
            #Delete all versions
            $Versions.DeleteAll()
            Invoke-PnPQuery
            Write-Host -f Green "`tDeleted All Previous Versions of the File!" #"$Item.FieldValues.FileRef
        }
        $global:counter++
    }
}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error Cleaning up Version History!" $_.Exception.Message
}
```

I've tried many scripts found on the web and with ChatGPT but the error returned is always the same.

I tried the trial version of the DMS Shuttle tool and it worked like a charm. But it's not free and you have to pay to clean up TB of data^^.

**UPDATE**

My research (thanks @mclayton) suggests that files larger than 2 GB are ignored.

So I tried this approach for a specific file:

```
# Define Parameters
$site1 = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite"
$relativePath = "/sites/MySite/Documents partages/Livraisons/subfolder/FRONT/_subfolder 2023/img.psb"

# Connect to SharePoint Online site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $site1 -Interactive

$context = Get-PnPContext
$file = $context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl($relativePath)

# load file object without versions property
$context.Load($file)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

#delete all versions
$file.Versions.DeleteAll()
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

And it worked instantly! No more :

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

But how can we now reproduce this action on all the files in a site's library?

Comment: Might be a known bug with ```Get-PnPProperty``` and large files - see https://github.com/pnp/powershell/discussions/3079

Comment: can't you just disable versioning ?

Comment: @SteveB, I did it, but it does not delete old version already created :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because I've finally found the solution!

The problem was thornier than expected because :

1. `Get-PnPProperty` doesn't handle large files (probably over 2GB, but perhaps even as little as 250MB). But this also applies to other commands such as `Get-PnPFileVersion`.
2. The `Get-PnPContext` approach is the correct one, but it had to be applied to a whole library of documents, and commands such as `Get-PnPList` or `Get-PnPListItem` didn't retrieve all the files (again, probably because they were too heavy or there were too many versions of a given file).

So, the trick was to use `Get-PnPFileInFolder` recursively and, most importantly, not to load version properties (or any other properties) until the file had been processed.

In this way, we get what we want: all versions of all files in a SharePoint library are deleted, even for large files or files with many versions. The script does take a little time to run, as all files will be scanned (except those in system folders), but it works like a charm  (tested on several libraries).

A little bonus: at the end of execution, the script generates a csv file summarizing all operations performed.

Modify the parameters `$siteUrl`, `$libraryName`, `$csvFilePath` according to your environment et voilà!

For my part, I was able to recover over 550GB of storage space available in SharePoint without spending any money on a software solution ;)

Oh, and one last point: if you don't want to do this again, remember to disable version control (if you're not using it, of course). The [SharePoint Diary](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/08/sharepoint-online-powershell-to-disable-versioning.html) scripts, especially the one called ***PnP PowerShell to Disable Versioning on a List***, work perfectly.

The script (hope it helps):

```
# Define Parameters
$siteUrl = "https://mycompagny.sharepoint.com/sites/Marketing"
$libraryName = "Documents"
$csvFilePath = "C:\Users\USERNAME\VersionCleanupReport.csv"

# Initialize array to store operation details
$operationDetails = @()

# Connect to SharePoint Online site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -Interactive

# Get all files in the document library
$files = Get-PnPFolder -ListRootFolder $libraryName | Get-PnPFileInFolder -Recurse -ExcludeSystemFolders

# Iterate through each file
foreach ($file in $files) {
    # Attempt to delete all versions of the file
    try {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Scanning file: $($file.ServerRelativeUrl)"

        # Get the file object without loading version properties
        $context = Get-PnPContext
        $fileObject = $context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl($file.ServerRelativeUrl)
        $context.Load($fileObject)
        $context.ExecuteQuery()

        # Check if the file has versions
        $versions = $fileObject.Versions
        $context.Load($versions)
        $context.ExecuteQuery()

        $versionsCount = $versions.Count

        if ($versionsCount -gt 0) {
            # Delete all versions of the file
            $fileObject.Versions.DeleteAll()
            $context.ExecuteQuery()

            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Deleted $versionsCount versions of file: $($file.ServerRelativeUrl)"

            # Add operation details to the array
            $operationDetails += [PSCustomObject]@{
                "File" = $file.ServerRelativeUrl
                "Operation" = "Deleted all versions"
                "Timestamp" = Get-Date
            }
        } else {
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkGray "No versions to delete for file: $($file.ServerRelativeUrl)"
        }
    } catch {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Error processing file: $($file.ServerRelativeUrl) - $_"

        # Add error details to the array
        $operationDetails += [PSCustomObject]@{
            "File" = $file.ServerRelativeUrl
            "Operation" = "Error"
            "ErrorMessage" = $_.Exception.Message
            "Timestamp" = Get-Date
        }
    }
}

# Export operation details to CSV file
$operationDetails | Export-Csv -Path $csvFilePath -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

# Disconnect from SharePoint Online site
Disconnect-PnPOnline
```